# How to have TypeScript property be typed according to a string representation of a type?

Tags: typescript

I have [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4KAFwTwBwU2AMQPYCcC2AeAMgSwNYJwAeEcAdgCYDOw1Equ5A5sALx0NPMB87wAbzChgAGwJwAXMDyFhoCAENCAfmkBBVKkVQcE4CTJVaAcnqMWJ4Cs4XW02UVIUawE0zLM4qKzfIBXdAAjb2BpRXIoHjAAXzAwAGNkcnpgADM0dGkUDH4hEXFCaTMuSwAaeRAlIuAAbQBGAF0y4AB6VroAC2R-UUpgCE7UZAB3YAiDLTRYyvBoeCRMgCY82cKpW25Z6rg1YE1tXRz0JdqTdZNGg2djN3NuX02WMMWMU-OJS+ujV3dyT28jwCwVC4Ui0TiiWSqQyb2yy1WBQkxXu5W2yg2DWabQ61G6vX6g2GYwm3mGqBmSRSEHSyyC8LeiNA6xRpWYJgqIh20jOADdFOJKJcWu0uj0+sAQsB+YLKdCabCTgkGScmSAWW5gSEfJyFBieSYZbghdjRXjxYShqNxuRJuS5dTaW9KCqVhx8szkZrAtqOeiag0AAym3H4iVSo2UWJAA) where I tried to get this working, but it's not erroring out as I would expect:

```
type Form<Like extends string = string> = {
    like: Like
    take?: Array<Like extends 'string' ? string : Like extends 'integer' ? number : any>
}

const form: Form = {
    like: 'string',
    take: [1], // should throw an error
}
    
type Form2 = {
    like: string
    take?: Array<Form2['like'] extends 'string' ? string : Form2['like'] extends 'integer' ? number : any>
}

const form2: Form2 = {
    like: 'string',
    take: [1], // should throw an error
}
const form2b: Form2 = {
    like: 'string',
    take: ['valid'], // should be valid
}
const form2c: Form2 = {
    like: 'number',
    take: ['valid'], // should throw an error
}
const form2d: Form2 = {
    like: 'number',
    take: [10], // should be valid
}
```

I tried those two ways. Basically I am representing schemas as JSON objects, and am going to specify them like this:

```
const form = {
    like: 'string',
    take: ['foo', 'bar']
}
```

I want to make sure that if I specify `like: 'string'` that `take` only accepts strings. Likewise, if `like: 'number'` or other types, then `take` only accepts things of that type.

Can this be done somehow in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an object generator function to get the desired typing.

And if you extend a `string`, `TLike extends 'string'` would never be true, so you'd have to extend the literal types instead, like `'string' | 'number'`.

```
function genFormObj<TLike extends "string" | "number">(formObj: {
  like: TLike;
  take: Array<TLike extends "string" ? string : number>;
}) {
  return formObj;
}

const form1 = genFormObj({
  like: "string",
  // @ts-expect-error
  take: [1],
});

const form2 = genFormObj({
  like: "string",
  take: ["1"],
});

const form3 = genFormObj({
  like: "number",
  // @ts-expect-error
  take: ["1"],
});

const form4 = genFormObj({
  like: "number",
  take: [1],
});
```

If you're using TS 5 or above, you can use the [`const` modifier on type `T`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/51865) and then you can simply extend a `string`.

```
function genFormObj<const TLike extends string>(formObj: {
  like: TLike;
  take: Array<
    TLike extends "string" ? string : TLike extends "number" ? number : unknown
  >;
}) {
  return formObj;
}

const form1 = genFormObj({
  like: "string",
  // @ts-expect-error
  take: [1],
});

const form2 = genFormObj({
  like: "string",
  take: ["1"],
});

const form3 = genFormObj({
  like: "number",
  // @ts-expect-error
  take: ["1"],
});

const form4 = genFormObj({
  like: "number",
  take: [1],
});
```

[Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mpK5BN)

Comment: Yes, this is the kind of solution with a class/constructor I was talking about.

Comment: I've added one more solution to my answer, you might want to check that out as well.

Comment: Looks good to me. :)  Also the fact that you are using `unknown` instead of `any`.

Comment: Notice I am not the one who asked the question.  Besides, I think our answers are complementary, and both valid, so I'd rather accept both.

Answer (score 0):

The code below seems to work as you expect.  The main difference is I have *not* given a default to the type parameter, since TS cannot desume the type of `take` in e.g. `const form: Form` from the assignment that comes after the declaration.  This also means that it is rather the type parameter that determines what is allowed in `like`, not the other way round.

To have `like` "drive" the type, you'd need a class/constructor, as opposed to simply a type or interface, that takes `type` and `like` as arguments: and its type parameter would still have no default, but would be inferred from arguments, indeed it is allowed to call a constructor without explicit type parameters.

```
type FormTake<Like extends string> =
    Like extends 'string' ? string :
    Like extends 'integer' ? number : unknown;

type Form<Like extends string> = {
    like: Like;
    take?: FormTake<Like>[];
};

const formS: Form<"string"> = {
    like: 'string',
    //take: [1],  // ERROR: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
    take: ["1"],
};

const formN: Form<"integer"> = {
    like: 'integer',
    //take: ["1"],  // ERROR: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
    take: [1],
};
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9gJwLYBUCGBrCAeAMgSyyggA9gIA7AEwGcobgF8KBzAPigF4AoKPqAkVLlqdAOQMmrMVAD89RsxZQAXL36DowyrShjm5FhAQz5FAK5IARsdVRzFDBTgB3CgG5u3UJFiIkeIRaZDp0kkocnFAA3up8ADZBKgJBnvxQwJgQssnwyOhYgVhsANoAup4Avp7cAMZwFAxQAGb%20AMq5-tgAROGs3ZExcVCJWMkSitIANMMA9LOZY1AlAIxlU3zzUACiAEq7APK7ySjg0GIW1sYy%20HTOwFBoNDT4LBRoVvHQwHAZZ3p9FhiYaLCDJErdFbddbcapeeqNB6tZAAOU6yB6BggRgQAy4Q3SozBeixOLEM3S81B4Mh0I2UC2e0Oxygp18EykQKgtyg90ez1e70%2031%20PnOlxsJhBWXBaxmcKAA)

Comment: Is there any way to avoid adding the type parameter to `Form<"string">`?

Comment: I have meanwhile expanded the answer.  Is that what you were looking for?  I could provide an actual example if you need...